# How can I see the queries executed on day x? (So I can find the DB change that is impacting performance.)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, logging

Since Day X (which is inconveniently just outside my DB recovery plan), I have been experiencing a significant performance degredation on an overnight process that runs Stored Procedure A, executed via an elastic job agent.

I've done a lot of troubleshooting on the query itself, without shedding any light. I definitely didn't alter it in the time period in question.

As I was trying to optimise other processes around this time, which use some of the same tables, my theory is that I inadvertently changed something that Stored Procedure A is dependent on - eg adding an index.

I would like to do two things:

- Get a list of every statement I executed on day X.
- Get a breakdown of the stored procedure's component statements on day Y, and see which elements were not resolving in a timely manner.

I'm hoping if I can compare these two lists, I'll find a causal link, which I can then undo.

UPDATE
I am on AZURE. This seems to invalidate most of the suggestions so far.

Comment: You'll need to use extended events to log the queries. You can't back in time if you haven't set this up already; though you *might* have some luck from the default trace.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, can you elaborate on "default trace"? I am new to this aspect of DB management.

Comment: There are by default 4-5 .trc files in the same directory that SQL Server keeps your ERRORLOGS...they can be viewed, filtered, etc. using SQL Server Profiler (copy off the server, then view on your box).

Comment: Schema change events from the default trace are also visible in SSMS Object Explorer under Reports-->Standard Reports-->Schema Change History.

Comment: If you're on a recent version of SQL server, use Query Store.

Comment: Thanks all. Will try these.

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to get historic detailed logs. I suggest you move on and concentrate on what you do have: a slow procedure. Run it with actual execution plans turned on in your representative environment and use that to see where the time is going. You presumably know how long the procedure in total used to take so you know how much time you're trying to find in the actual execution plan - you may even find a lot more than that that can be easily fixed.